# Xcode "Missing Submodule" warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode6

I'm using Xcode6 GM to create a Coacoa Touch Framework (a new function in Xcode6), then this framework is included into my app.

Everything is fine (works fine), except that I get warnings in "#import". What is the root cause?

[image]

Answer (score 57):

I ran into the same problem and eventually fixed it by adding my project headers into the umbrella header. When you create a new framework it should start with a single `.h` file titled by the project (in your case `DirectProximityFramework.h`).

Inside this file is a comment:

> In this header, you should import all the public headers of your
>   framework using statements like `#import <DirectProximityFramework/PublicHeader.h>`

So just add your `GeofencingHelper.h` file in this file:

```
#import <DirectProximityFramework/GeofencingHelper.h>
```

This should remove all of your warnings!

Comment: Hi @Firo - I am getting this warning even though I'm doing this.

Comment: EDIT: Stupidity on my end. I hadn't updated my imported framework appropriately.

Comment: @Julian, glad you figured it out!

Comment: What if the warning happens in the test target and I don't want to make public all the headers I need for testing?

Comment: One thing to add is to make sure that the headers are properly added to either the Public, Private, or Project sections of the Headers section in your framework target's Build Phases.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe, you can stop this warning by adding following line to "DirectProximityFramework.h"

```
#import <DirectProximityFramework/GeofencingHelper.h>
```

...etc

I suggest to check

[Target your framework] -> Build Phases -> Headers -> Public

Answer (score 3):

In case if it is not your framework and there is nothing to do you can disable warning in such way

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wincomplete-umbrella"
#import <DirectProximityFramework/GeofencingHelper.h>
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Note - it is not a fix, it just hide the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue and all the solutions above didn't fit me, since the file wasn't supposed to be in the umbrella header.

So if this is your own framework and that particular file shouldn't be in the umbrella header, make sure it isn't marked `public` in the target membership section.

That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and my solution was..

When you create the framework project.Your project automatically "yourProjectName.h" file gets created, In this header file import class class.

In my case I am getting `missing submodule 'MSFramework.MSLocationManager' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]`this warning.

resolved by Just importing

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    # import "MSLocationManager.h"

    //! Project version number for MSFramework.
    FOUNDATION_EXPORT double MSFrameworkVersionNumber;

    //! Project version string for MSFramework.
    FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char MSFrameworkVersionString[];
```

here I just add the `# import "MSLocationManager.h"`in header file.

Answer (score 0):

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like

`#import <GameworkSDK/GWObject.h>`

like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <GameworkSDK/GWObject.h>

//! Project version number for GameworkSDK.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double GameworkSDKVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for GameworkSDK.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char GameworkSDKVersionString[];
```

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem cocoa pods

my solution was real simple but took forever for me to figure out.

- when i ran $ pod install it generated a workspace for me in the same dir as my .xcodeproj file.
- however i had already created a workspace to use as its parent directory.
- so then i simply deleted my old workspace and went with the one that pods created

[image]

---

glhf!

Answer (score 0):

Set header search path in your project setting:

**TARGETS / Build Settings / Header Search Paths**
        "$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/[YOUR PROJ NAME]/[YOUR PROJ NAME].framework/Headers"

Now import the header file.

```
    #import <DirectProximityFramework.h>
```